# jQuery: re-enable selected and disabled option

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to re-enable the selected and disabled option from the drop-down list once they are "removed" from the added list.
Can anyone please help me. Many thanks in advance.
Following is what I've got so far, and here http://jsfiddle.net/N2jyy/2/ demo page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Add-btn').live('click',function() {
        $(document.body).append($("<div>"));
            var a = $('#a').val();
            $("#tabName tr:first").before("<tr><td class='greyed'><input type='hidden' name='added_a' value='" + a + "'>" + a + "</td><td style='background:transparent;'><input type='button' class='delete' value='Remove'></td></tr>");
            $("#a option:selected").attr("disabled", true);
    });
    $('#tabName td .delete').live('click',function() {
        // here I want to re-enable the select option ...removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#tabName td .delete').live('click',function() {
    var val = $(this).closest('tr').remove().find('input').val();
    $("#a option[value='" + val + "']").attr("disabled", false);
    return false;
});
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/S2FrE/), what this does it goes up to the `<tr>` then down to the `<input>` while at the same time removing the `<tr>`, then we're using that value to select the option you want to re-enable.

Comment: I like this one better, but posted mine just for an alternate way :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, you can do this by index as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Add-btn').live('click', function() {
        $(document.body).append($("<div>"));
        var a = $('#a').val();
        $("#tabName tr:first").before("<tr><td class='greyed'><input type='hidden' name='added_a' value='" + a + "'>" + a + "</td><td style='background:transparent;'><input type='button' class='delete' value='Remove'></td></tr>");
        $("#a option:selected").attr("disabled", true);
    });
    $('#tabName td .delete').live('click', function() {
        var delindex = $(this).parent().prev().find('input').val() - 1;
        $("#a option:eq(" + delindex + ")").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```